# Is it possible to instantiate two LocationManager objects?

Tags: android, android-location

I want to have two separate callbacks for calls to requestLocationUpdates(), each one monitoring for different intervals (one of time, one of distance). Is this possible? Or can I use one LocationManager instance and call requestLocationUpdates() on it twice, declaring a separate object to implement onLocationChanged() as its last arg/param?

Comment: Without never using LocationManager I'd say it shouldn't be impossible to register two LocationListeners using requestLocationUpdates(..) as there's a cleanup method removeUpdates(LocationListener) to remove them. As for using same LocationListener implementation twice, I'd say do not do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can register twice. You can even use the same listener object each time if, for example, you want to register for more than one provider.

You only need to "removeUpdates" once for each listener. So if you have registered the same listener twice, you only need to call removeUpdates once.

However, it's possible that if you are registering for different intervals, that both listeners will still get all of the updates. The interface makes no guarantees about update frequency, and the parameters passed are just hints. It may even vary from phone to phone - on some phones each listener could get updates at the requested freqencies, and on another phone both listeners could get all of the updates.